# Certificates for Apple push Notification

Tags: php, ios, ssl, github, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying use open source [apns-php](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/).

In the [certificates' instructions](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/CertificateCreation), it is written how to generate the certificates.

I've ended up with two certificates:
1. server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem
2. entrust_root_certification_authority.pem

From your knowledge where should I upload them to?
(I'm doing this for the first time)

Comment: suspicious... Apple APNS instructions on Google Code. The steps are incomplete and does not mention the meaning behind.

Comment: Follow this tutorial, great for learning apple push notification- http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Well i don't think it a new thing that instructions are not complete :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the "tutorial" in the link provided in your question, you should use **server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem** as your Sandbox APNS certificate.

You should upload to a folder out of your web root. Example:

if you web root is `/var/www/`,  you can upload to `/var/certrepo/server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem`. Point your PHP script's certificate to this location, and you'll be able to use the certificate.

The **entrust_root_certification_authority.pem** has no use in your PHP script.

---

Important: Note that the certificate is a **Sandbox certificate**, which you use it to test out your APNS logic. To apply to production environment (which allows higher push notification rate), use **Production certificate** and connect to production APNS server.

Comment: Great, but for what is the entrust root certification?

Comment: From the tutorial, it's for you to test the connection in your local machine :) In short, DO NOT follow this tutorial; it's strange. Follow the raywenderlich.com one. Simple & easy.